# Merge specific elements within list in r

Tags: r

I have created a list like this:

```
l<-list(">1","ATTCGGT","GCCCTCGT",">2","GGGAATCCT",">3","CCCAATTGG","TTGGCCCTA")
```

I want to merge all the elements other than the ones containing ">"
For eg, my output should look like this:

```
l
[[1]]
[1] ">1"
[[2]]
[1] "ATTCGGTGCCCTCGT
[[3]]
[1]">2"
[[4]]
[1]"GGGAATCCT"
[[5]]
[1]">3"
[[6]]
[1]"CCCAATTGGTTGGCCCTA"
```

I can merge 2 list elements using paste0 but I have to do that individually and then delete the the second element from the list manually. How do I make R merge all elements other than the ones containing ">" automatically and provide me with the list I desire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the list to a plain character vector and create a grouping vector g that groups each > component into a single group and consecutive non-> elements into a single group.  Then use tapply to paste all elements in each group together and remove the names.

Note that since every element of the input list l has only one component it would be easier to use character vectors rather than lists in which case ul would be the input and we could omit the simplify argument to tapply.

```
ul <- unlist(l)
ok <- grepl(">", ul)     # TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
g <- 2*cumsum(ok) - ok   # 1 2 2 3 4 5 6 6
unname(tapply(ul, g, paste, collapse = "", simplify = FALSE))
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] ">1"

[[2]]
[1] "ATTCGGTGCCCTCGT"

[[3]]
[1] ">2"

[[4]]
[1] "GGGAATCCT"

[[5]]
[1] ">3"

[[6]]
[1] "CCCAATTGGTTGGCCCTA"
```

Comment: When I run the second line of your code, R says object "ok" not found. Is there a package I must add?

Comment: Sorry must have pasted the wrong lines in.   Have fixed.